# access stats using the vimeo API

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

i want to access the vimeo stats with the vimeo API to automatically get a list of the most viewed videos.

i am trying to access `https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos/stats` with an access token, but i get the following error.

```
{
    "error": "Your access token does not have the \"stats\" scope"
}
```

is it not possibile to access the stats using the API, because i can't find a scope named "stats"? it only works from the stats admin page where i can download the stats export as an csv.

i read in a post from over a year ago that the stats api is not available yet, does anyone know if this is still the case, i could not find anything in the vimeo docs.

Answer (score 0):

Stats are still unavailable via the Vimeo API.